# Silverlight does not support dynamic resources: what does this mean?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

It is said here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903925(VS.95).aspx

Silverlight does not support dynamic resources. All resource references to keyed resources in XAML are static. For more information, see Resources Overview.

I looked at resources Overview but still don't understand what they mean. Can someone explain: does it mean I cannot xamlreader to change user intreface dynamically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [XAML-Reader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189076(v=vs.95).aspx) in silverlight to build dynamically changing interfaces. Set for example the ControlTemplate of a control to a ControlTemplate you have loaded or created with XamlReader.

However you can not change resources (for examle a ControlTemplate in a [ResourceDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary.aspx)) during runtime and expect them to change the content in currently used elements.

Comment: OK thanks I didn't know it was even possible to change resources in WPF :)